# Play With Numbers Programming Challenge (mean value of subarrays)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, statistics

I'm trying to solve this  [Play With Numbers](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/play-with-numbers-2/). I have passed the test cases but, I kept getting time limit exceeded.
Can someone help me improve its performance in order to pass the time limit, please?

**Problem**

> You are given an array of n numbers and q queries. For each query you have to print the floor of the expected value(mean) of the subarray from L to R.

**Input**

> First line contains two integers N and Q denoting number of array elements and number of queries.
>
> Next line contains N space seperated integers denoting array elements.
>
> Next Q lines contain two integers L and R(indices of the array).

**Output**

> print a single integer denoting the answer.

**Time Limit:**

1.5 sec(s) for each input file.

**Result Time:**

Input 1: 1.999309
Input 2: 1.998019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);

int n = 0, q = 0;
cin >> n >> q;

vector<int> nums(n);

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> nums[i];
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    float ans = 0.0f;
    int leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;

    cin >> leftIndex >> rightIndex;

    leftIndex = leftIndex - 1;
    rightIndex = rightIndex - 1;

    for (size_t i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++)
    {
        ans = ans + nums[i];
    }

    ans = ans / (rightIndex - leftIndex) + 1;
    cout << floor(ans) << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running this O(*R - L*) loop for each query:

> ```
> for (size_t i = leftIndex; i <= rightIndex; i++)
> {
>     ans = ans + nums[i];
> }
> ```

You could obtain each sum in O(1) time if you stored the array as cumulative sums instead.

$$
\begin{align}
S_1 =&\ A_1 \\
S_2 =&\ S_1 + A_2 \\
S_3 =&\ S_2 + A_3 \\
 \vdots& \\
S_N =& S_{N-1} + A_N
\end{align}
$$

The tricky part is that \$S_N\$ could be as large as \$10^{15}\$, which requires more than 32 bits.

Comment: I found out there's built-in function for this. It's called `std::partial_sum`

Answer (score 1):

Simply calculate the sum of array elements while taking them as input.

Do not use a `for` loop, for doing so for every `l` and `r`.

Also, divide by `(r-l+1)` (instead of `(r-l)`), as this gives the total numbers between `l` and `r`. 
I Hope it helps.